# Get the full image path when the image is clicked on any web pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a console script (assuming jquery is applied) where I need to get the full image path when the element is clicked. The element can be a image itself or it can be background image or it can be a image inside a div or nested elements.

The outcome is only the full path of the image.

I have tried with the below code, it works when the element clicked is an image iteself. But I am not able to get the full image path if the element is a background or housed inside a iframe or something else. For example when I click image in this it would not give a image path since its frame https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_images_trulli or here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

But it would vey well give in google image search

How can I achive this for all page so I get the full path of the image selected

```
//jquery already added
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    let srcElement = e.srcElement;

    console.log($(srcElement).attr("style"))

    if (srcElement.nodeName == 'IMG') {
    srcElement.style.border="red 4px dotted"
    alert(srcElement.currentSrc);
        console.dir(srcElement);
    }
//if the element is div or has sub elements get the background image with full path

}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple logic in this.

1). Check if the clicked element has `src` attribute, if yes, then fetch the src value and use it wehere you want.
2). If the clicked element don't has `src` attribute, then check if it has `background-image` in css and fetch that value.

I have made a demonstration for you.

Thanks me later.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
let target = e.target;
if(target.src){
alert(target.src);
}
else if(target.style.backgroundImage) {
let bg = target.style.backgroundImage;
alert(bg.slice(5, -2));
}
})
```

```html
<img src="https://preview.ibb.co/cyESoU/img1.jpg" style="width: 400px;max-width:100%">

<p>Onclick no action because no src or background-image</p>

<div style="width: 400px;height: 250px;background: url(https://preview.ibb.co/cyESoU/img1.jpg) no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;max-width: 100%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h2>HTML Image</h2>
<img src="example.jpg" alt="text" id="image">
<script>
alert(document.URL+"/"+$('#image').attr('src'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you try this code? It takes the domain name and the path to the image and combines it

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use jQuery
2. Do not use alert for debugging

I've full path for `img` by e.target.src.

BTW, if you need the URL of background-image:

```js
let url = getComputedStyle(e.target).backgroundImage;
console.log(url.substring(5, url.length-2));
```

Comment: could you help me where can I change the code?

Comment: You can `addEventListener` on your specific element, not the whole document. 
In such a case, use tools like codpen.io to share your code.